# How to refreshen when you sleep too much or sleep in the afternoon?

Tags: personal-care

There are many cases where we sleep more. Like losing control of time or our body or being sick, or pulling an allnighter etc..

When that happens we wake up feeling more exhausted, more sleepy, faint etc.

So  what is the best way to refreshen ourselves in such a situation?

Comment: I feel that this may be off-topic because it is just asking for a mind hack of how to feel more awake. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @michaelpri so mind hacks arent life hacks? Then which SE site can we post mind hacks at?

Comment: No mind hacks aren't life hacks. You may be able to ask some "mind hacks" on [productivity.se].

Answer (score 0):

A common hack to this would be to drink coffee or another source of caffeine, then go back and take a 15 min nap. Wake up when your alarm hits 15 mins...humans sleep in 90 min cycles this is scientifically proven.

The goal here is, drink coffee, take a power nap, after 15 mins, your body starts reacting to the caffeine and in turn will boost your awareness.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too! I love taking afternoon naps and sometimes, I wake up feeling extremely tired and more sleepy.

What I do is to drink a cup of water, then eat juicy or crispy fruit from the fridge, such as an apple, orange, or grapes. It take a bit time for my body to wake up. Sometimes if I feel like it, I would take a shower as well.

Usually eating fruit works for me. Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Fruits work for me as well